# Structured Search and replace to match fluent API

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

In the below code sample I'm trying to replace the obsolete AddColumn with it's new form AddStringColumn

```
Database.CreateEntityTable("PayrollDefinition")
    .AddForeignKeyColumn("BenefitDefinition", ColumnProperty.NotNull)
    .AddColumn("LastInRange", DbType.String)
```

I want to create a Resharper structured search (and replace), but I don't understand the syntax as explained [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__SSR__Searching_for_Code_with_Pattern.html)

As search pattern I have

```
$tableBuilder$.AddColumn($columnName$, DbType.String)
```

As replace pattern I have

```
$tableBuilder$.AddStringColumn($columnName$, 255)
```

where tableBuilder is expression of type TableBuilder and columnName is exactly one argument.

It seems to get the correct search hits, but the replace doesn't do a thing.
Also I don't think it's finding multiple chained calls of the same method.

How should I formulate my search/replace pattern to replace the AddColumn method with the AddStringColumn method?